# Permissions / Forms for Task List Submission Only

Tags: permissions, custom-form, forms-authentication

I'm currently setting up a SharePoint 2010 site and my division will be using the Task List functionality to manage our work.

One of the requirements is for customers external to our division be able to submit tasks via a web form. However, these customers should not be able to access any other list functionality i.e. the should not be able to view the list or items, nor edit or delete items.

SharePoint seems to allow me to set up the NT AUTHORITY\AUTHENTICATED USERS group to have a level of access to the list that enables Adding of items but this also enables Viewing. I tested this, but the user I tested it with received an Access Denied message when opening the form link (propagation delay? Something else?).

What is the right approach to enabling users in the wider organisation to submit jobs directly to our SharePoint list?

1. Should I just accept that they'll be able to view tasks in addition to submitting? Assuming I can fix the permissions not working -- any hints?.
2. Can I set up a custom form page and set specific permissions (AUTHENTICATED USERS) to it, just leaving my list with the normal "contributors" permissions? How does one do this?
3. Some other magical option I've missed?

The customer form should only have a subset of the fields we use in the division. I'm currently accomplishing this using Content Types.

I'd prefer not to use InfoPath if possible and have no access to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When Add Items permission is assigned to a permission level the View Items permission is automatically assigned to it. So, you can create a separate page/form and expose your list fields in it. When user click Ok/Submit, you will need to run your code with Elevated privileges so that a list item is created.

Comment: A separate page / form? Created with what? Where is the code running?

Comment: Just saw your update that you don't have access to VS, so creating a page with code behind won't be an option.